# Where does maven wildfly plugin deposit its deployed WARs?

Tags: maven, deployment, wildfly-10

I have been deploying `mvn wildfly:deploy` successfully for a few days, and I always imagined that deployment would place my foo.war in the standalone deployments folder, but all I can find are some foo.war empty directories in deployments/tmp.

- Where is maven sticking the deployed files?
- Is mvn wildfly:deploy suitable for production use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wildfly-maven-plugin uses management operations to deploy the archive created by Maven. It does not move the file itself as that would not work for remote deployments. Where the deployment content is stored is up to the application server itself.

The `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments` directory is used by the `deployment-scanner` to deploy applications copied there. See the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Application+deployment#Applicationdeployment-DeployingUsingtheDeploymentScanner) on the deployment scanner for more details.